# Rails Peddler gem: Using Amazon MWS Feeds API for adding products to Amazon seller central store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-mws, peddler

I am trying to add a product to the amazon seller account using amazon mws feeds api. I am using Ruby on Rails and peddler gem. But i couldn't find any documentation/example of how to add a new product. There's a function given to submit feed ([link](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/peddler/MWS/Feeds/Client#submit_feed-instance_method)). But i am not sure about how to send 'feed_content' parameter. Is there any example of how to do it? I am able to make the connection:

```
  client = MWS::Feeds::Client.new(
  marketplace_id:        'marketplace_id',
  merchant_id:           'merchant_id',
  auth_token:            'auth_token',
  aws_access_key_id:     'aws_access_key_id',
  aws_secret_access_key: 'aws_secret_access_key'
)
```

Kindly share any example or any suggestions of how to add a product. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[FeedContent](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html) is the actual content of the feed itself, whether XML or flat file.  You also need a [FeedType](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html).  Have a look at the [MWS Feeds API overview](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_Overview.html) to learn about the process.  No matter the language or platform you use, the process is the same.

A request is going to look like this:

```
POST /Feeds/2009-01-01 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: mws.amazonservices.com
User-Agent: <Your User Agent Header>

?AWSAccessKeyId=0PB842ExampleN4ZTR2
&Action=SubmitFeed
&FeedType=_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_
&MWSAuthToken=amzn.mws.4ea38b7b-f563-7709-4bae-87aeaEXAMPLE
&MarketplaceIdList.Id.1=ATVExampleDER
&SellerId=A1XExample5E6
&ContentMD5Value=ExampleMd5HashOfHttpBodyAsPerRfc2616Example
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&SignatureVersion=2
&Timestamp=2009-01-26T23%3A51%3A31.315Z
&Version=2009-01-01
&Signature=SvSExamplefZpSignaturex2cs%3D
```

and the body, which contain the products you are adding looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>M_EXAMPLE_123456</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>56789</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>ASIN</Type>
        <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Example Product Title</Title>
        <Brand>Example Product Brand</Brand>
        <Description>This is an example product description.</Description>
        <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
        <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
        <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
        <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
        <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
      </DescriptionData>
      <ProductData>
        <Health>
          <ProductType>
            <HealthMisc>
              <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
              <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
            </HealthMisc>
          </ProductType>
        </Health>
      </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the response. It is really helpful. I have few more questions: having gone through the mws documentation, for some feeds there's no xml schema available. Then how do we create a xml file for those feeds? And also for some feeds xsd is available, then how do we create xml from those xsd?

These might be rookie questions as i am new to web development.

Comment: You can find the xsd's right here: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help-page.html/ref=au_1611_cont_scsearch?ie=UTF8&itemID=1611

Comment: I'm not a ruby programmer, so I don't know if there are any tools like the ones I have for C#.  Do a search on StackOverflow, you're bound to find something.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)